# What is the difference between conjugating retourner with “être” and “avoir”?

Tags: grammaire, auxiliaires

What is the difference when conjugating the verb *retourner* with *être* and *avoir* ?

Answer (score 8):

The verbs that make up what we call "Dr. Mrs. Vandertramp", the ones conjugated with *être*, are only so when **intransitive** — when there is no object.

> Elle est descendue du grenier.
>
> Elles sont sorties ce matin.
>
> Ils sont retournés en Angleterre.

Many of these verbs can also be used in a **transitive** way — they can act on another object.

When that happens, there are three differences:

1. They are conjugated with *avoir* instead of *être*.
2. Instead of the participle agreeing with the subject, the usual rules of object agreement apply.
3. The meaning is usually different.

> Elle a descendu le coffre du grenier.
>   
>  → Auxiliary is *avoir*, no agreement on *descendu*, means "brought down" instead of "came down".
>
> Elles ont sorti leurs crayons de leurs étuis.
>   
>  → Auxiliary is *avoir*, no agreement on *sorti*, means "took out" instead of "went out".
>
> Ils ont retourné leurs vestes.
>   
>  → Auxiliary is *avoir*, no agreement on *retourné*, means "turned around" instead of "returned".

You can check the different meanings in a dictionary like WordReference that gives the structure and some examples for each definition. [Here's the entry for *retourner*.](http://www.wordreference.com/fren/retourner) Let's compare two definitions:

[image: retourner vtr vs. retourner vi]

The first definition in the picture is labelled ***vtr***. That means *verbe transitif*, so those differences apply. It's conjugated with avoir, no agreement, and has the meaning "send back" at right.

The second definition is labelled ***vi*** for *verbe intransitif*. It's conjugated with *être*, does show agreement, and has the meaning "come back" at right.

There are actually lots of definitions for "retourner" as a transitive verb, so check out that entry!

Comment: I think *WordReference* missed the boat by not using your example of *retourner* being used intransitively ("Ils sont retournés en Angleterre"), for yours, being in the *passé composé*, highlights the first two important differences/points much better than theirs does.

Comment: +1 sans détour pour un propos destiné à un apprenant. Après... la transitivité, on sait ce que j'en pense et déduire de cela l'auxiliaire... on s'exposera à nombreuses bévues. Le lecteur curieux considérera §813 + Rs & Hs associés dans Grevisse pour s'en convaincre.

Comment: comme exemple avec avoir retourné, je suggèrerais plutôt "il a retourné sa veste" ou "il a retourné la crêpe avec sa spatule". Dans retourner un film, on change de sens RE-TOURNER (avec RE- pour "again"), et dans ce sens on n'utilise pas l'auxiliaire être.

Comment: @radouxju Oui, et voici les attributs que je voulais, si tu relis ma réponse ! :) Mais il est vrai que « retourner un film » n'est pas l'expression la plus courante. Je la remplace.